# (SSRS) Tablix advanced grouping, hide cells and align cells

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to achieve a result like below (edited in paint):

[image]

But so far I have only achieved this:

[image]

As you can see, I get whitespace cells between the timestamps and values above, probably due to the cells above that is manuipulating the tablix layout.

How can I make the values cells become "snapped" next to the timestamps like the first picture?

This is how it looks in SSRS:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to your image, seems you could not achieve your goal in your current Tablix design . you need to change your report design using list , like below:
[image: table structure01]
[image: table structure01]

(add one more table in the list to display header)
In this scenario , you should make sure that you have  the full records under the group Meter2 and Interval2  to make up the column group cells.
Otherwise you could get like below:
[image: result of no enough data]